# How do you only include the parts of jQuery that are used by your app

Tags: javascript, jquery, static-analysis

For example, let's say I have a list of the jQuery object functions and its prototype functions:

```
/* jQuery object functions example
   jQuery.isArray
   jQuery.isFunction
   jQuery.proxy
   jQuery.ajax
*/

/* jQuery prototype functions example
   jQuery.fn.init
   jQuery.fn.val
   jQuery.fn.css
*/
```

This is a very small subset of jQuery and I may not necessarily want to include all of jQuery when I know I will only use these functions.  I could copy and paste from jQuery, but there are a lot of dependency chains between the jQuery functions and local functions and vars used within the jQuery closure, which are hard to grab all of by hand.  My list is also quite bigger than this, this was just used as a small example.

My question is if there is a tool to do a static analysis of jQuery whereby you list the functions you want (like above) and get back the needed bits of code.

Comment: You definitely should not do this. The other bits don't matter. It's *never* a good idea to hack apart 3rd part libraries, and doing so to save a few kilobytes is a very bad idea.

Answer (score 3):

There is a mechanism for making your own custom build called jQuery Builder: http://projects.jga.me/jquery-builder/.

You really ought to first look at the minified version of jQuery as served by a popular CDN though because that will very likely be in the browser cache already and perhaps even have better performance than a smaller customized version that isn't yet cached.  For reference, the minimized and gzipped version of jQuery 2.0 is only 29k, smaller than many images in a web page.

Comment: That's interesting, I just wish there was a bit more fine grained control over the builder.  29k is fairly enticing however, and it looks like with the stuff I need it'll be 19k.  Thanks a ton, if I don't find another solution, this will be my go to.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't know about the BYO jQuery tool suggested by jfriend00 so +1 for that.

Another alternative depending on what browsers/functionality you need to support may be using a jQuery replacement like [zeptojs](http://zeptojs.com)  or [minifiedjs](http://minifiedjs.com). These libraries use jQuery syntax and come in around 3-9k gzipped/minified.